# How to create a Many-to-Many Relationship with unique column of a specific value using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship

I want to create a `User` which has multiple `Item`s but only one item of a specific type. The tables will look something like this.

1st table: `item`

| id | type | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first | name1 |
| 2 | first | name2 |
| 3 | normal | name3 |
| 4 | normal | name4 |
| 5 | normal | name5 |

2nd table: `user`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 3 | name3 |
| 4 | name4 |
| 5 | name5 |

The `User` will select at the start an `Item` that he can only select as his first item. This means I could either create a `OneToOne` and a `ManyToMany`-Relationship like this:

1st table: `item` unchanged

2nd table: `user`

| id | name | first_item_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | 1 |
| 2 | name2 | 1 |
| 3 | name3 | 2 |
| 4 | name4 | 1 |
| 5 | name5 | 2 |

3rd table: `user_normalitem`

| user_id | item_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 3 |

Or just create a `ManyToMany`-Relationship like this (`Item`s that are `firstItem`s are marked bold):

1st table: `item` unchanged

2nd table: `user` unchanged

3rd table: `user_item`

| user_id | item_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | **1** |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | **1** |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | **2** |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | **1** |
| 5 | **2** |
| 5 | 3 |

The problem is that if I would now insert a new relationship to `user_item` like this:

`user_item_addition`

| user_id | item_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | **2** |

it would go through without any exception, error or warning.

My first question is: "Is this second approach with `user_item` possible or do I have to go for `user_normalitem`?"
Secondary is more an opinion: "Would you instead go for the first approach to make sure that it is unique? Or are multiple Relationships (`OneToOne` and `ManyToMany`) between two tables just bad behavior?

Comment: if you want the DB to ensure a 1-to-1 relationship, the easiest is to make it a column in the `user` table. Use a junction table for 1-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you question correct, you are on a totally wrong path.

You have User and you have items and you have items picked by users.
That means you need three tables.

User table has some columns like id, name etc…

Items have columns like id, name, etc…

Items picked by user have 3 attributes
Userid (foreign key to User Id),
itemid (foreign key to item id),
isFirstItem (1 if item is picked as first item else 0)

To make sure that the first item is unique you have multiple options.
As I would do it in application layer, you can also add a trigger or you can add a 4 table only for the first item with a primary key on user id so that only one item can be added there.

Comment: I think the point of his question is how to ensure that there's only one item marked `isFirstItem=1` for each user.

Comment: Might be. But this is something I would do in application logic and possible check with a trigger

Comment: I have improved my wording within the question. Can you please read it again?

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, I understood that a user can have multiple items but I didn't quite understand if the same item can be owned by different users.

In the case where the same instance of an item can be owned by different users then you need a many-to-many relationship which will produce the following tables: Users, Items and the middle relationship that, just for the sake of this example, I will call UsersToItems. The UsersToItems will contain its own primary key and the two foreign keys pointing to Users and Items. In this case, if you need only a single instance of ownership between the Users and the Items then you can use the unique clause on the foreign keys to avoid repeated t-uples of ownership, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Items (
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE UsersToItems(
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    idExtUser int NOT NULL, 
    idExtItem int NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (idExtUser) REFERENCES Users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (idExtItem) REFERENCES Items(id),
    UNIQUE(idExtUser, idExtItem)
);
```

In the case where an item can be owned only by one User then you need a one-to-many relationship where the Items table will possess its own primary key and a foreign key to the Users table. So, if you want to achieve uniqueness for this case too, you need to set as unique the pair 'item type' and 'the foreign key to the Users'.

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Items (
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    idExtUser int NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (idExtUser) REFERENCES Users(id),
    UNIQUE(type, idExtUser)
);
```

Instead, if you simply need to have an Items table that allows only different types of items regardless of its relationships then apply the unique clause only to the 'type' column.